# How do I extend shower cover plate without replacing a tile

Tags: tile

I had my shower tiled and, unfortunately, the job was sub-par.
I am not wondering if this can be somehow fixed via workaround, without replacing my tile. Maybe some sort of cover plate extension?

Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with the manufacturer for parts for your model #. They might have a larger cover plate. You could also bring it into a plumbing supply store and see if they have a larger one. You'd be amazed at the parts a good plumbing store has. Last but not least, there is usually a bead of white caulk around cover plates in showers this color. A good bead might just cover that opening if all else fails.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Shower Renovation Cover]
If Caulk isn't an acceptable fix, these renovation covers will do the trick. This specific unit can be purchased here: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Delta-Shower-Renovation-Cover-Plate-in-Stainless-RP29827SS/203722677

Answer (score 0):

How big are your tiles?  Looks like you would only have to remove the one to right of the valve, cut a new tile to fit,and put it back in.

Answer (score -1):

What is the question? It looks like a fat finger of calking could seal this and should have been done,  I usually make sure to have the tile extend at least 1/4” closer to the valve but a cheap job ?  well I have seen this many times, caulking can seal it and prevent problems, but it would be a contract issue in most cases and would be off topic and if you paid them you accepted the work. 
Yes you can take to court , but a fat finger caulking job would seal it and If another contractor agrees it is industry standard they will win and you may be responsible for there Court fees. 
Without a specific question I would vote to close. 
If you ask is it a good job I would say more like a handyman or diy , not a professional that did tile Just saying.